# Codeigniter blank page - Severity: Compile Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have codeigniter application which working well in justhost. I am trying to transfer it to bigrock host. But in new host its not working I can only see blank page with 500 error,no error logs in cpanel. Followed many solution in stackoverflow but couldn't fix(innitioally i thought its .htaccess problem), and now I tried define environment variable to development, I can see php error which says as below

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Compile Error
>
> Message: Can't use method return value in write context
>
> Filename: models/Home_model.php
>
> Line Number: 77
>
> Backtrace:

Home model screen shot

[image]

login function which is in home model:

```
public function login($data) { 


    if(filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $res = $data['email'];
    }
    else {
        $settings        = get_setting();
        $pre = $settings->id_prefix;

        $res =  trim($data['email'],$pre);
    }
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');

            $this->db->join('profiles', 'profiles.email = users.email','left');
            $this->db->where('user_status','1');
            $this->db->where('users.email', $res);
            $this->db->or_where('matrimony_id',$res);
        $chk_qry = $this->db->get();
        //$chk_qry = $query->row();
        //echo $this->db->last_query();die;



    if ($chk_qry->num_rows() == 1) {
      $pass = $this->encrypt->decode($chk_qry->row()->password);

      if($data['password'] == $pass) {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $chk_qry->row()->user_id); 
        $usr_qry = $this->db->get('profiles');

        if(!empty($usr_qry->result())) {
          if($usr_qry->result()[0]->profile_status != 2) {
            if($usr_qry->result()[0]->profile_status != 4) {
              if($usr_qry->result()[0]->profile_approval == 1) {
                $status = 1;
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',$usr_qry->result()[0]);
                $data1['date_time'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
                //$data1['user_id']=$usr_qry->result()[0]->user_id;
                $data1['matrimony_id']=$usr_qry->result()[0]->matrimony_id;

                $query = $this->db->where('matrimony_id',$data1['matrimony_id']);
                $query = $this->db->get('active_members');
                if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
                 $this->db->where('matrimony_id',$data1['matrimony_id']);
                 $this->db->update('active_members',$data1); 
               } else {                   
                $this->db->insert('active_members', $data1);
              }
                        } else { $status = 2; } // Profile Not Approved
                      } else { $status = 7; } // Profile Deactivated
                    } else { $status = 5; } // Profile Deleted or Banned
                } else { $status = 6; } // No Accounts Found
            } else {    $status = 3; } // Ivalid Password 
        } else {        $status = 4; } // Email not exist
        return $status;
      }
```

**I wonder how this same script working fine in justhost.**

Comment: Add your code in that screen shot to the post please.

Comment: OP has added same code @Sand

Comment: try by removing empty from `if(!empty($usr_qry->result())) {`

Comment: thanks for quik replies. Updated php version from 5.4 to 5.6 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem!!! silly me,

**Updated php version from 5.4 to 5.6**